# Combine part of the ouput and input as a new input in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

As you see there are four output nodes that have the same names as the nodes in input layer, which means that the output of four nodes will be combined with the next input in order to create a new input, just like RNN in some way. However, with `tf.nn.static_rnn` it seems that one layer can only combine the output with the input of the same layer.

[image: Image Attachment]

So my question is: how can I combine part of the ouput and input as a new input in tensorflow, just like in the graph above?